# Stop redirect loop in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I need to redirect the following URL:

`example.com/amp-home`

to

`example.com/amp-home/amp`

I've set the following 301:

```
Redirect 301 /amp-home example.com/amp-home/amp
```

But when loading `example.com/amp-home` it redirects but ends up looping and the URL looks like:

`example.com/amp-home/amp/amp/amp/amp/amp` etc...

Comment: _"but ends up looping"_ - of course it does, because `Redirect` does prefix-matching on the current URL path. Use RedirectMatch with a pattern anchored at the start and end, or a combination of RewriteCond & RewriteRule.

Comment: Try: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/amp-home/?$ /amp-home/amp`